# Fazer um script Jquery pra ser executado apenas em celulares

Tags: jquery, html

Não tenho como postar o código agora, então serei o mais claro possível.

Estou fazendo um site naquele padrão single page, onde cada sessão do site possui o tamanho exato da tela. Isso é feito via Jquery(aquele script básico de pegar o tamanho da tela).

O site não foi concebido para ter suporte para celulares, mas o cliente pediu apenas um ajuste no tamanho da tela quando o site é acessado via celular(no formato retrato). Como não tenho como dar maiores explicações vou direto a pergunta

Como fazer um script JQuery que fosse executado apenas em celulares? Ou como alterar o que já existe para que o mesmo não dê suporte a mobile (nesse caso eu corrigiria o Css com media query).

Comment: cara, uma outra opção é você usar media queries. Pegue as resoluções mais populares de telefones e exiba o campo apenas quando a regra obedece uma dessas midias querys. Mais informações nos links: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries e http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/

Comment: Teu problema é muito amplo, se o problema é com o layout então não é bem um problema a se resolver com jquery (a não ser que seja uma gambiarra). O layout tem que ser construído pra ser responsivo, na maioria dos casos é impossivel pegar um layout normal e passar pra responsivo, não é apenas uma questão de mediaqueries, tem que resolver no html também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo, uma exemplo e espero que lhe seja útil quanto a sua dúvida:

```
function isMobile() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (userAgent.search(/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i) != -1;
}
```

E então para efetuar uma ação baseado na resposta:

```
if (isMobile()) {
   // aqui, o script que você deseja que seja executado caso o acesso esteja sendo feito via Mobile/Celular
   alert("Executado via Celular!");
}
```

Comment: Removi o `return true` porque ele era um pouco redundante =) - espero que entenda a edição como uma ajuda pra ti

Comment: O código funcionou ao detectar o usuário mobile, mas não consegui criar alternativas pra resolver um problema secundário que é tela retrato tela paisagem. Apesar disso com o código consegui remover o suporte para mobile e assim fiz o ajustes necessário via media query, Então valeu, era exatamente o que eu estava procurando.

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, obrigado pelas devidas edições!

Answer (score 3):

Esse método verifica se o dispositivo que está sendo acessado é `PC` ou `MOBILE`, mas recomendaria usar `viewport` e `mobile first` (técnica para criação de sites responsivos), facilitária muito mais sua vida e vc não precisaria de `JS` para organizar a página.

```
function isMobile(){
    var a = navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera;
    return /android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile|o2|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|smartphone|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce; (iemobile|ppc)|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a);
}
```

Como usar:

```
if (isMobile()) {
     alert("Código executa somente em mobiles");
}
```

Comment: Não é um site responsivo, foi solicitado apenas um ajuste. Sabe aqueles clientes que não sabem o que quer?

Comment: seu, já tive muitos... (-_-)

Comment: Parece que não funcionou

Comment: @BrumazziD.B. Removi o `return true` e `false` porque eles eram um pouco redundante e adicionei um exemplo =) - espero que entenda a edição como uma ajuda pra ti.

Comment: sim sim, entendi o que foi feito, vlw